# How can I organize a dictionary in crescent form from another dictionary

Tags: python

I want to print a dic from the number of "chairs" in that:

```
'{'VARANDA': [{'tables': [0], 'chairs': 20, 'free': 1}, {'tables': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'chairs': 4}, {'tables': [0], 'chairs': 6}]}'
```

when I print this, it should return:

```
VARANDA:
 5 tables de 4 chairs.
 1 tables de 6 chairs.
 1 tables de 20 chairs.
```

but it is returning:

```
VARANDA:
 1 tables de 20 chairs.
 5 tables de 4 chairs.
 1 tables de 6 chairs.
```

i'm using a for loop to print:

```
for area in sorted(dicCopy):
            print(f'{area}:')
            for i in dicCopy[area]:
                print(f' {len(i["tables"])} tables de {i["chairs"]} chairs.')
```

how can i print this from the number of chairs in a crescent way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `key` for custom sorting of your values (I used here the number of chairs) :

```
d = {'VARANDA': [{'tables': [0], 'chairs': 20, 'free': 1}, {'tables': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'chairs': 4}, {'tables': [0], 'chairs': 6}]}

for area, lst in d.items():
    print(f'{area}:')
    for d2 in sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x['chairs']):
         print(f' {len(d2["tables"])} tables de {d2["chairs"]} chairs.')
```

output:

```
VARANDA:
 5 tables de 4 chairs.
 1 tables de 6 chairs.
 1 tables de 20 chairs.
```